# Read the first column values of a HTML table with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3

I got a table:

```
<table id="ItemsTable" >​
    <tbody>
   <tr>
     <th>
       Number
     </th>
     <th>
       Number2
     </th>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>32174711</td>     <td>32174714</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>32174712</td>     <td>32174713</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I need the values 32174711 and 32174712 and every other value of the column number into an array or list, i'm using jquery 1.8.2.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `map` method:

```
var arr = $('#ItemsTable tr').find('td:first').map(function(){
     return $(this).text()
}).get()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QsaU2/

From jQuery `map()` documentation:

> Description: Pass each element in the current matched set through a function, producing a new jQuery object containing the return values.
>   .
>   As the return value is a jQuery-wrapped array, it's very common to get() the returned object to work with a basic array.

Comment: @Huangism Yes, it's needed, your selector only returns the first td of the first tr. http://jsfiddle.net/EB4rN/

Comment: You can reduce the selector to `$('#ItemTable td:first-child')`

Comment: @undefined ok i see, wouldn't first-child work better in this case? maybe even using > to be more precise in the css selector?

Comment: Also, I don't believe `.get()` is necessary.

Comment: @Shmiddty That's an another option, Why do you think `get` is not necessary? There is a difference between `$.map()` and `map()`. [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) returns a jQuery object.

Comment: @undefined: (`+1`ed you for good answer and DEMO) I suppose `get()` is redundant as get returns the underlying DOM objects of the jQuery objects returned by map. In this case though we already have the result of `text()` which is not a jQuery object but a simple string. This will give you the exact same result in this case: `console.log($("#ItemsTable tr td:first-child").map(function() {return $(this).text();}));​`

Comment: @undefined: `get` or no `get`, both fiddles return the same array (`["32174711", "32174712"]`) in the console as far as I can see.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl I can see all methods and properties of a jQuery object, one is a jQuery object and another one is actual array.

Comment: @undefined: Ahhhhhh.. now I see. Sorry for not seeing it! Very good :) when not using `get` the result still is a jQuery object. I can call jQuery methods on it such as `console.log(arr.eq(0))` for example but can't do that when using `get()`. Very nice. You are absolutely correct in that case. Even though the results look the same in the console, without `get` it still is a jQuery wrapper. Nice one. Off course, if that is what the user wants then leaving `get()` away is right I suppose but if you want the underlying values without being a jQuery object `get()`  is needed.

Comment: This answer and discussion was very useful to me for a similar need.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 16):

```
var arr = [];
$("#ItemsTable tr").each(function(){
    arr.push($(this).find("td:first").text()); //put elements into array
});
```

See this link for demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/CbCNQ/

Answer (score 3):

```
// iterate over each row
$("#ItemsTable tbody tr").each(function(i) {
    // find the first td in the row
    var value = $(this).find("td:first").text();
    // display the value in console
    console.log(value);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8aKuc/

Comment: Isn't that a lot of internal traversing? First `.each` then for each row another jQuery wrapper on `this` plus the `find`. Not sure how map internally works but using `.find` only ones sounds "cheaper" than using it each time inside the loop. `+1` anyway as it does give you the individual values.

Comment: This answer is probably the least efficient. Just sayin.

Comment: I can't speak on the internals of `map`, but I imagine it does something similar.

Answer (score 2):

well from what you have, you can use first-child

```
var td_content = $('#ItemsTable tr td:first-child').text()
// loop the value into an array or list
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Shmiddty/zAChf/

```
var items = $.map($("#ItemsTable td:first-child"), function(ele){
    return $(ele).text();
});

console.log(items);​
```