# Retrieve first column value of checkbox selected row of an HTML table and modify the DB accordingly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So here is the table below
[image]

I wanted to store the (#) of every checkbox selected row in an array variable preferably which I can later use them to modify the database, viz: **change a certain DB field where the id is: 37, 39, 42, 46, etc.**

[A similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752834/read-the-first-column-values-of-a-html-table-with-jquery), which provides a much more broader solution

The code which selects the row after `checkbox:selected`

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
      $('td :checkbox').bind('change click', function () {
              $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('highlight', this.checked);
            }).change();


    } );
</script>

<style type="text/css">
  .highlight td{
      background-color: #a2c4ab;
      }
</style>
```

Any reference or guidance would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to get rows where a checkbox is selected:

```
var selector = '#myTable tr input:checked'; 
$.each($(selector), function(idx, val) {
  // iterate here
});
```

And then for each row you can get values with e.g.:

```
var id = $(this).parent().siblings(":first").text();
var update = $(this).parent().siblings(":first").next().text();
```

Meaning get my  parent and get the first sibling, or next to first sibling etc. You can adjust that for your table.

Putting it altogether below - note posting to your DB totally depends on information not in your question so you can just do an AJAX post or something.

```js
$('#test').on('click', function() {
  var updates = [];
  var selector = '#myTable tr input:checked'; 
  $.each($(selector), function(idx, val) {
    var id = $(this).parent().siblings(":first").text();
    var update = $(this).parent().siblings(":first").next().text();
    updates.push({id: id, update: update});
  });
  
  // test values
  console.log(JSON.stringify(updates));
  
  // post to DB - fill in your details
  //$.ajax({
  //  url: 'your_script.php',
  //  type: 'post',
  //  data: updates,
  //  success: function() {
  //    alert('done');
  //  }
  //});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>DB update</th>
      <th>Checker</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Hughie</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" id="foo1" /><label for="foo1">Foo1</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Dewey</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" id="foo2" /><label for="foo2">Foo2</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Louis</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" id="foo3" /><label for="foo3">Foo3</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Chewey</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" id="foo4" /><label for="foo4">Foo4</label></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button id="test">Get checked IDs</button>
```

Comment: Just tried your answer, Great!!!..
But could you please tell me what `console.log(JSON.stringify(updates));` does? Does it converts all the extracted values to string?

Comment: It's just something in the sample - not necessary at all and you can just do `console.log(updates)` no problem. For a big array, the `stringify` just removes a lot of the formatting and you can see it 'at a glance'

Comment: Worked for me thanks a lot. Although I am not good with AJAX, started learning right away. Thanks for your effort