# Get HTML table column values in array

Tags: jquery, arrays, html-table

I have this HTML table markup

```html
    <table id="tblPtPrtDtl">
  <tbody><tr>
    <th>File Number</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td id="prfn"><button id='prtfilenum' type='button' ">3344</button></td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td id="prfn"><button id='prtfilenum' type='button' ">4323</button></td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="prfn"><button id='prtfilenum' type='button' ">3466</button></td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td id="prfn"><button id='prtfilenum' type='button' ">5432</button></td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td id="prfn"><button id='prtfilenum' type='button' ">3455</button></td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td id="prfn"><button id='prtfilenum' type='button' ">4563</button></td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

How can i get the values for column (File Number) in array, using map function?

I tried the following code but i get empty array, any idea why?

```
 var arr = [];
        $("#tblPtPrtDtl tr").each(function () {
            arr.push($(this).find($('tr:not(:first)')).text()); //put elements into array

        });
```

Comment: And what you tried so far??

Comment: Be more specific

Comment: I gave the column an id and I used this code

    var r = $("#tblPtPrtDtl #prfn").text();
            alert(r)
i get all the values but how i can push them in array

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752834/read-the-first-column-values-of-a-html-table-with-jquery .. and remember don't duplicate the IDs .. ID should be unique

Comment: perfect, how to avoid the header

Comment: I tried function shift() but did not work

Comment: the header is avoided itself while you just select the TDs .. another method you can use `$('tr:not(:first)')`

Comment: The first value is empty

Comment: ,2323,34554,4444

Comment: if you loop through TR TDs so this is not from the header .. this because your first TD in first row after header is empty .. update your question with the working code to let me know what you reached so far

Comment: How can I skip it,

Comment: while I don't see you code .. But you can skip it by using `$('tr:not(:nth-child(2))')` and see if it works for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142245/discussion-between-ahmad-abu-maizar-and-mohamed-yousef).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try it

```
var col_Array = $('#tableid td:nth-child(3)').map(function(){
       return $(this).text();
   }).get()​;
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = $('#tblPtPrtDtl tr').find('td:first').map(function(){
 return $(this).text()
}).get()

function readval(){
alert(arr)
}
```

```css
<table id="tblPtPrtDtl ">
  <tbody><tr>
    <th>File Number</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td id="prfn "><button id='prtfilenum' type='button' ">3344</button>
</td>
<td>Maria Anders</td>
<td>Germany</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="prfn"><button id='prtfilenum' type='button' ">4323</button></td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="prfn "><button id='prtfilenum' type='button' ">3466</button>
  </td>
  <td>Roland Mendel</td>
  <td>Austria</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="prfn"><button id='prtfilenum' type='button' ">5432</button></td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td id="prfn "><button id='prtfilenum' type='button' ">3455</button>
  </td>
  <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
  <td>Canada</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id="prfn">
    <button id='prtfilenum' type='button' ">4563</button></td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='Get' type='button' onClick= "readval();return false " >Get Vals</button>
<table id="tblPtPrtDtl" >
    <tbody>
   <tr>
     <th>File Number</th>
     <th>Name</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  <tr>
  <td id="prfn "><button id='prtfilenum' type='button' ">3344</button>
  <td>Maria Anders</td>
<td>Germany</td>
</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td id="prfn"><button id='prtfilenum' type='button' ">4323</button></td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

ok i found the way of getting the values of first column in array

```
 function gettbldta() {
        var arr = [];
        $("#tblPtPrtDtl tr:not(:nth-child(1))").each(function () {
            arr.push($(this).find("td#prfn:eq(0)").text()); //put elements into array
           arr.shift
        });
        alert(arr)
```