# get the column header on cell click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to get the column header of the table on cell click.I have tried as below.Now all the th value is displaying.now to get the relavent th value.

```js
$('td').click(function() {
    var txt = $(this).text();
 var label=$(this).closest('tr').find('.label').text();
 var header=$(this).closest('table').find('th').text();
    console.log(txt + ':' +label + ':'+header);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead id="thead">
  <th></th>
  <th>Week 1 </th>
   <th>Week 2 </th>
   <th>Week 3 </th>
   <th>Week 4 </th></thead>
  <tbody id="tbody"><tr><td class="label">test1</td><td>5</td><td>2</td><td>7</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td class="label">test2</td><td>9</td><td>15</td><td>12</td><td>4</td></tr><tr><td class="label">test3</td><td>32</td><td>12</td><td>23</td><td>28</td></tr><tr><td class="label">test4</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr></tbody>
  <tbody id="tfooter"><tr><td>Total</td><td>145</td><td>120</td><td>157</td><td>162</td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This might help you https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-get-table-header-value-when-td-is-clicked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make this work you need to get the `th` which matches the index of the clicked `td` in the row. To do that use `index()` and `eq()`, like this:

```js
$('td').click(function() {
  let $cell = $(this);
  let txt = $cell.text();
  let label = $cell.closest('tr').find('.label').text();
  let header = $cell.closest('table').find('th').eq($cell.index()).text();
  console.log(txt + ':' + label + ':' + header);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead id="thead">
    <th></th>
    <th>Week 1 </th>
    <th>Week 2 </th>
    <th>Week 3 </th>
    <th>Week 4 </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbody">
    <tr>
      <td class="label">test1</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">test2</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">test3</td>
      <td>32</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>28</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">test4</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody id="tfooter">
    <tr>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td>145</td>
      <td>120</td>
      <td>157</td>
      <td>162</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the column value in array on total count click

Comment: Sure, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43534069/get-html-table-column-values-in-array)