# .NET Core View page's values to JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am developing an application in .NET Core MVC. In my View page, I have a table like this table here. Which generates using foreach loop.

```
foreach (var items in Model){
   // generate Table
}
```

[image]

What I want is, Not to show this table. Instead, When the Page loads, Pass this values to **JavaScript Array** and show some dynamic charts.

For example, The Amount column in the table. I want to get the amount values in javascript like:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var amountValues = [1000, 3000, 2000, 1100];
});
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752834/read-the-first-column-values-of-a-html-table-with-jquery if it helps you

Comment: Is there any reason you need to change the `amountValues`? Why don't set it at the server side by `Model`? What do you mean by dynamic charts? What is your expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could serialize the Model into a javascript class and use as you want:

```
var myModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model));
for (var item in myModel)
{ 
   var amountValue = item.Amount;
   //push to array etc.
}
```

Comment: why the surrounding `@{ }`?  That's a code block so nothing should be output in the html.

Comment: yea you are right, must have been some rapid prototyping a little too rapid :) It's removed now